# Is there a way to prevent ObjectOutputStreams from being truncated by the JFrame being closed?

Tags: java, eof, truncation

What I am trying to do is prevent my OOS, saved in a file, from being truncated. I am assuming this is the reason for which I am unable to load up data at arbitrary times. This is also a reasonable conclusion considering the data that is stored within the output file seems to be incomplete.

I have tried saving the data instantly after the JFrame has closed out, but this hasn't worked.

```
f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        new Data().save(UnitPacer.this);
    }
});
```

This is the save method (which is held within the Data class seen above):

```
public static void save(Serializable data, String filename) throws IOException {
    try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new 
        ObjectOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get(filename)))) {
        oos.writeObject(data);
    }
}
```

Also, this data is saved on a clock, invoking the same save method every 1000 ms or 1 second. So, therefore, I am assuming that the reason it is being truncated is that it is being interrupted by the JFrame being exited during saving.

Please let me know if any more information is necessary in solving this problem.

Thank you

Comment: Well, you should be using a lock of some kind to prevent the frame and clock from trying to write the contents at the same. Maybe start with the [Sychroization section of the Concurrency trial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html) as well as the [Intrinsic Locks and Synchronization section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html)

Comment: Ok, but this error was occurring prior to the addition of the first snippet of code. So the problem still stands, with that being said, I will look into those links.

Comment: One way is to do your saving on a separate Thread, which you should be doing anyway, since file I/O does not belong in the AWT event dispatch thread where it can delay processing of events.  The JVM will not exit while there are non-daemon threads running, unless it is forcibly terminated.